# Libvirt iptable chain LIBVIRT_FWX has no effect on interface internal traffic

Tags: iptables, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I created a libvirt network in *open* mode and added the iptable rules that would have been created for a *nat* mode network. My plan is to basically create a *nat* network but add some custom iptable rules on top. (It's easier to use open mode and manage the rules myself.) Example use case: No network internal communication between VMs except from vmX to vmY,vmZ. So far everything worked as before with *nat* mode.

However, when I added the rules to block internal com, I noticed the following:

Little Background: Libvirt creates the following iptable chains:

- `LIBVIRT_FWI` : Incoming traffic
- `LIBVIRT_FWO` : Outgoing traffic
- `LIBVIRT_FWX` : Internal traffic (within eg virbr0)
- `LIBVIRT_INP` (irrelevant for now)
- `LIBVIRT_OUT` (irrelevant for now)

While FWI and FWO work as expected, from eg eth0->>-virbr0 and eth0-<<-virbr0, the FWX chain for internal communication has no effect.
`iptables -L LIBVIRT_FWX -v` shows

```
Chain LIBVIRT_FWX (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  anywhere             anywhere
```

My custom chain:

```
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr2 virbr2  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr2 virbr2  192.168.122.10       anywhere            
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr2 virbr2  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Now, my guess is that iptables don't apply to network interface internal communication. Am I right in this assumption?

My options are probably:

- I did something wrong and iptable rules **do** apply

  - The FWX chain is at the top of FORWARD, so no other rule should interfere
- I have to create a network for each VM in order block traffic between them

I'd really appreciate a second opinion on this matter.

For completeness:

```
Chain DMZ_LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
58531   24M ACCEPT     all  --  virbr2 any     192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
  133 10336 REJECT     all  --  virbr2 any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

```
Chain DMZ_LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
55149   21M ACCEPT     all  --  any    virbr2  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
   66  3960 REJECT     all  --  any    virbr2  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```